# Инициализация ArrayList

Tags: java

Пытаюсь создать пустой ArrayList определенного размера что-бы позже вставлять в эти места объекты и читать их. В документации указан конструктор:

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity)
```

Constructs an empty list with the specified initial capacity.

Исходя из-этого я сделал так:

```
public static ArrayList<Object> foo = new ArrayList<Object>(6);
```

Собственно на этом этапе все нормально, но при отладке foo.size() == 0, а foo.add(index, object) вызывает NullPointerException, как быть? Может Какой другой контейнер использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capacity - это емкость. Т.е. размер массива, который заранее создается при указании параметра initialCapacity. Нужен он в первую очередь для оптимизации работы ArrayList, т.к. позволяет избежать ненужного пересоздания массива и последующего копирования данных из старого массива в новый.

Кроме того, список - это упорядоченная последовательность элементов. А вы пытаетесь работать со списком, как с массивом.

Comment: Тут очень сильно запутывает возможность задавать индекс добавляемого аргумента, это осталось от старых версий для обратной совместимости? или этому есть другое объяснение ?

Comment: добавлю лишь, что _размер_ и _ёмкость_ массива: разные вещи. Размер показывает, сколько элементов в массиве на самом деле есть, а ёмкость -- сколько туда можно эффективно положить.

Comment: @sonniy Скорее здесь должно смущать название метода. Т.к. вообще говоря он предназначен для вставки элемента в произвольное место списка. insert наверное было бы более понятным именем.

Answer (score -1):

Может для вашей задачи подойдет HashMap:

```
HashMap<String, String> hm =new HashMap<String, String>();
    hm.put("1", "TRU !!!");
    System.out.println(hm.get("1"));

    hm.put("2", "NEW TRU !!! NEW ");
    System.out.println(hm.get("2"));

    String oldStr = hm.get("2");
    String addStr = "ХэшКод";
    hm.put("2", oldStr+" - "+addStr);
    System.out.println(hm.get("2"));
```