# Найти сумму всех четных и сумму нечетных элементов массива

Tags: java

Начал изучать java. Получил такое задание "Найти сумму всех четных и сумму нечетных элементов массива". В итоге написал этот код. Но IDEA выдает ошибку 
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2". Не могу въехать почему и как исправить. 
Кроме этого, числа которые должны попадать в динамический массив even попадают в odd  и наоборот. Надеюсь, кто то откликнется :)

```html
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class task7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] a;
        Scanner z = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of elements in the array");
        int n = z.nextInt();
        a = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i <= (n - 1); i++) { //Принимаем все числа массива
            Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter" + " " + i + " " + "number of the array");
            int b = x.nextInt();
            a[i] = b;
        }



        List<Integer> even = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> odd = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i = 0; i< n; i++){
            if (a[i]%2==0) {
                even.add(i);
            }
            else {
                odd.add(i);
         }
        }
        int sumEven = 0;
        int sumOdd = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            sumEven +=odd.get(i);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
          sumOdd+=even.get(i);
        }
        System.out.println("Array of even numbers is: " + even);
        System.out.println("The sum of even numbers is " + sumEven);
        System.out.println("Array of odd numbers is: " + odd);
        System.out.println("The sum of odd numbers is " + sumOdd);
    }

}
```

Comment: В List объектах не может быть количество элементов n (используйте в цикле list.size)

Comment: т.е я не могу указать ранее созданную переменную ?

Comment: Можете, но количество элементов в листах меньше, вы же распределяете

Comment: все, понял, спасибо )

Comment: [Похожая статья](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/186260/Инициализация-arraylist)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of elements in the array");
        int command = s.nextInt();
        int numbers[] = new int[command];
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { //Принимаем все числа массива
            System.out.println("Enter" + " " + i + " " + "number of the array");
            numbers[i] = s.nextInt();
        }

        List<Integer> even = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> odd = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] % 2 == 0) {
                even.add(numbers[i]);
            } else {
                odd.add(numbers[i]);
            }
        }

        int sumEven = 0;
        int sumOdd = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < even.size(); i++) {
            sumEven += even.get(i);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < odd.size(); i++) {
            sumOdd += odd.get(i);
        }

        System.out.println("Array of even numbers is: " + even);
        System.out.println("The sum of even numbers is " + sumEven);
        System.out.println("Array of odd numbers is: " + odd);
        System.out.println("The sum of odd numbers is " + sumOdd);
    }
}
```

Не надо обявлять 2 сканнера, один можно использовать везде в классе.
Выучи Forech loop, он поможет в итерации массивов (я сам не использовал чтобы тебе был понятен код).
И я бы посоветовал давать переменным логичные имена (а не "a, b, n, x и тд.), чтобы ты сам и другой человек не терялся в коде. Если будут вопросы по моему коду задавай, не стесняйся.

Comment: Удивительно. Спасибо за помощь и за советы.

Comment: Пожалуйста, обращайся :)